# When I return a Map and Number, they don't destructure properly (undefined)

Tags: javascript

## Context

I have a function that passes out a Map of ints, and an unrelated int. Here's an example that *does* work:

```js
const myFunction = () => {
    let color_map = new Map();
    color_map.set(111, 222);
    color_map.set(333, 444);
    color_map.set(555, 666);

    let rando = 777;
    return {color_map, rando};
}

const {color_map, rando} = myFunction();
console.log("Results:", color_map, rando)
```

## My Code

My actual code is very similar:

```
const makeColorMap = (img) => {
    let color_map = new Map();
    let psize = 0;
    // ...
    return {color_map, psize};
}
```

```
// makeColorMap() is passed in as 'method'
const {color_map, psize} = method(arr);
```

However, when I run this, both come out as undefined.
[image: Console's output, showing both are undefined]
Does this have to do with the anonymous function or something? I'm really lost.

Maybe related, but in a previous iteration, the first two elements of the Map were being put into `color_map` and `psize`, respectively. What gives?

Comment: Please post a minimal running code snippet that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Questions for Psychics 300: *"I have this code here that works; my code is very similar but doesn't work. Why?"* So how do they differ? What is your actual code? the one that does not work? Did you check that `method` contains the right method (you said it's a callback)? Did you check what `method(arr)` actually returns? Without the destructuring, the exact return value!

Answer (score -1):

Your code works, but you are not calling makeColorMap, instead you call some method:

```js
const makeColorMap = (img) => {
  let color_map = new Map();
  let psize = 0;
  // ...
  return {
    color_map,
    psize
  };
}

const arr = [];

const method = makeColorMap; 

const {color_map, psize} = method(arr);

console.log(color_map, psize);
```

What you need to do in your app is to make sure that `method` is indeed a `makeColorMap`, which is probably not the case in your app